# How to solve the issue with python cplex installation?

Tags: python, linear-programming, solver, cplex

I installed **IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio Community Edition**.

I have 64-bit Windows 7.

My python is `Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:42:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32`

Cplex is under `MYCPLEXHOME\cplex\python\2.7\x64_win64`. I do `python setup.py install` in this directory.

Then I do:

```
import cplex
```

but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import cplex
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cplex\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from . import _internal
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cplex\_internal\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from . import _list_array_utils
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cplex\_internal\_list_array_utils.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import _pycplex as CPX
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cplex\_internal\_pycplex.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pycplex_platform = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cplex\_internal\_pycplex.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pycplex_platform', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cplex\_internal\_pycplex_platform.py", line 23, in <module>
    from cplex._internal.py27_cplex1270 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: I think you are mixing 32 bit Python with 64 bit Cplex. With DLLs these things have to match.

Comment: There is no 32 bit Cplex in IBM website. How do I make it work with 32 bit python?

Answer (score 1):

When i call my (old non-actively used windows-based) python-distribution, it output's something like (a bit different because of Anaconda-based distribution):

```
Python 3.4.4 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Feb 16 2016, 09:54:04) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

Without beeing too sure, i read this as:

- build on a 32-bit system: `on win32`
- build for a 64-bit system: `MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)`

In your case it looks, like you are using a 32-bit distribution of Python (`MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)`), which you mix with a 64-bit based interface of CPLEX. That won't work!

So your steps are:

- check if there is 32-bit-based CPLEX-interface and install it
- if not, you will need to reinstall python (compiled for 64-bit)

Effects may be non-simple, but i highly recommend 64-bit based Python (which even seems to be more the standard right now)!

(Erwin was a bit faster with his comment)

Comment: There is no 32 bit Cplex in IBM website. How do I make it work with 32 bit python?

Comment: Where do I get 64 bit python? I use Windows 7.

Comment: @alwbtc Googling immediately showed 32-bit versions of CPLEX. The question though is: is there a 64-bit version (recommended) with a 32-bit interface? I'm not sure. So sure, you can run the 32-bit CPLEX on your 64-bit windows with your 32-bit Python. But really, i highly recommend reinstalling Python!

Comment: @alwbtc Really? I'm amazed by those question from someone with such a high score. Did you try ```www.python.org``` :-)? 64-bit is currently more the standard! (Some excerpt from some of the official downloads: ```The binaries for AMD64 will also work on processors that implement the Intel 64 architecture. (Also known as the "x64" architecture, and formerly known as both "EM64T" and "x86-64".) They will not work on Intel Itanium Processors (formerly "IA-64").```)

Comment: OK, I thought it was made only for AMD machines. And where is 32 bit cplex download link? Could you provide me the link?

Comment: On the same source whe you got your version. (If CPLEX let's you install the 32-bit version in Win64; but well don't do it)

Comment: It only presents 1 version: 64-bit cplex.

Comment: @alwbtc Yeah, and probably no Linux-version too ;-). Look, it might be not as nice as you want, but there is a way to use the 32-bit version (as it's marketed like that). I don't know if you can use it in Win64 (no problems at all in theory; but it's IMBs decision in regards to distribution and installer). As i don't have an account there i can't and won't do all that work for you especially as it's useless. It's still the wrong approach (unless you state why you need your 32-bit python)

Answer (score 1):

With CPLEX 12.7 there is no 32-bit installer on Windows.  See the [detailed system requirements](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27019100) here.  If you want to use 32-bit Python, you'll have to use an older version (e.g., CPLEX 12.6.3).